# After render, some objects turn to basic mesh

Tags: cycles-render-engine

When I render, one collection of objects remains/reverts to basic shape.
I've tried the toggling enable render, checking cycles settings but no luck.
I am a beginner at blender and never came across this before. I did earnestly try to search if anyone else came across this, but always came up with people not seeing their rendered object.
What have i checked/unchecked that caused this for the render output?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is cylinder in your scene that is hidden from preview but not from render:

[image]

Delete that last Cylinder or click on that camera button at the right side to hide it from render and you will be okay

Comment: Thanks for the immediate reply. The problem was carelessness and not paying attention. Thanks again for your time and the lesson provided.

Comment: @Jeffri: If Miko's answer helped you, please check the checkmark left to his answer